Does a bump out actually need a vented soffit?
I have a small kitchen bumpout with its own shingled roof. There's no ridge venting, obviously, like a typical roof would have, or anything like venting along the side of the house. The soffit is the only point of air exchange. I'm also using a "smart" (variable) vapor barrier on the interior. That should provide moisture control.
I was advised to actually replace the vented soffits with unvented. Might anyone have further input? Appreciate any ideas

this could be dependant on your location and how exactly the roof meet the rest of the house.  In my area, Fla. the soffiting would need to be vented and there would need to be some opening either to the main roof or on the roof itself for proper venting.

Most roofs need ventilation.  Ventilation is done with low intakes(soffits) and high exhaust(ridge vents, roof vents, gable end vents).

Right, both of your points are true. That is how my actual roof is: vented soffits with a ridge vent at the top. However, this bumpout does not have any venting along its top. So it has a vented soffit, but then that's it. It's flush with the side of the house without a top exhaust. For reference, I'm in NY, Zone 5 I believe.

A couple of those mushroom cap(whatever they are called) roof vents should be easy to install.

What's the insulation situation? One strategy is to make it a "hot roof" by completely filling the cavity.

So, prior to what I just did, the insulation was: haphazardly filled chunks of fiberglass insulation, capped off by batts of faced insulation, stapled to the outer and inner walls, just beneath the roof. That said, there was a lot of sag, and the facing was not continuous as a result. I've now replaced all of that with Rockwool, and stretched a smart vapor barrier (Intello Plus) across, sealing any air penetrations and sag. In theory, that's roughly equivalent to what was there, but with less air movement and better moisture control

The cavity was completely filled with fiberglass, and now with Rockwool instead
